# How to disable Office and My Computer on a PC for a specific user?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

We have Office 2007 on a Windows XP PC and don't want a specific user to use the installed Office. We also don't want him to be able to view My Computer on that specific PC.

Is there anyway this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link which helps me solve my issue: http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ms-office/Word/Install_Word_For_Only_One_User.htm